# Outlook2007/2010はHTMLメールのstyleブロック内のCSSを無視する？

Tags: html, css

HTMLメールのコーディングで困っており、質問させてください。

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/
こちらの情報によればoutlook2007/2010はhead内でのCSSの定義およびクラス名セレクタをサポートしているはずなのですが、以下のHTMLでは無視されてしまいます。
何か記述間違いなどありますでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-2022-jp">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ja">
    <style type="text/css">
    .test {color:red;}
    </style>
</head>
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" bgcolor="#FFF" style="margin:0; padding:0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust:none;">
    <div class="test">DIVテスト</div>

    <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFF" style="margin: 1% 0 2% 0;">
        <tr>
            <td class="test" width="100%" valign="middle">テスト</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```